# javascript conflict with prototype js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, prototypejs

I have following piece of code and this has started breaking after i included Prototype.js into the page.

```
          function JsonArrayByProperty(objArray, prop, direction) {
            if (arguments.length < 2) throw new Error("sortJsonArrayByProp requires 2 arguments");
            var direct = arguments.length > 2 ? arguments[2] : 1; //Default to ascending

            if (objArray && objArray.constructor === Array) {
                var propPath = (prop.constructor === Array) ? prop : prop.split(".");
                objArray.sort(function (a, b) {
                    for (var p in propPath) {
                        if (a[propPath[p]] && b[propPath[p]]) {
                            a = a[propPath[p]];
                            b = b[propPath[p]];
                        }
                    }
                    a = a.match(/^\d+$/) ? +a : a;
                    b = b.match(/^\d+$/) ? +b : b;
                    return ((a < b) ? -1 * direct : ((a > b) ? 1 * direct : 0));
                });
            }
        }
```

It breaks at following lines with error

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'match' 

   a = a.match(/^\d+$/) ? +a : a;
   b = b.match(/^\d+$/) ? +b : b;
```

Comment: Well, apparently `a` and `b` are objects, not strings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem most likely starts on this line:

```
for (var p in propPath) {
```

Once you add prototype.js to your page, you cannot use the common (but incorrect) shortcut of iterating over an array using `for(foo in bar)`. That's because array elements are no longer simple strings or floats, they are full-fledged "extended" objects that happen to evaluate back to strings or floats if you iterate over them correctly.

```
for(var i = 0; i < propPath.length; i++) {
```

will get you back on track.

Comment: thanks mate...it turns out the calling function for this was the culprit where the age old issue of JSON.stringfy(xxxx) not working with prototype surfaced and i will have to make changes to existing code for reason you mentioned.

The code was screwing up array in this line of calling function

    'var finalData = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(someData));'

Comment: There's a great page about this here: http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/ -- read the section about NOT using for/in to loop over an array. If you refactor your code to use `yourArray.each()` instead, you'll have a much happier time.